# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv

I'm trying send image using python socket. But ı have a problem. I want to convert image to string then convert string to image. I can't create empty jpg file, because i will use this code video streaming and recording.

my client code is here

```
import socket
import cv2
import threading
import time 
import base64

Soket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2344
#Buffer_Boyutu = 2360
Soket.bind(('', port)) 
Soket.listen(20)
c,asa = Soket.accept()
c.send('')
camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)

def img_to_str(image):
    ret, buff = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    c.send(str(len(base64.b64encode(buff))))
    str_image = base64.b64encode(buff)
    return str_image



ret,image=camera.read()

str_image = img_to_str(image)

print(len(str_image))
time.sleep(0.02)
c.send(str_image)
time.sleep(5)
Soket.close()
```

my server code is here

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

Soket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
port = 2344
Buffer_Size = 1024
Soket.connect(('',port))


def str_to_image(str_img):
    file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(str_img), dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, 0)
    cv2.imshow('img.jpg',image)

size = ''
while size == '':

    size= Soket.recv(1024)
    if size != '':

        Buffer_Size = int(size)     

        str_img = Soket.recv(Buffer_Size)
        if len(str_img) == Buffer_Size:
            str_to_image(str_img)


Soket.close()
```

I have this error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 331
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server2.py", line 27, in <module>
    str_to_image(str_img)
  File "server2.py", line 15, in str_to_image
    cv2.imshow('img.jpg',image)
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I will make a stream video programming and ı must use opencv image. Plaese help.

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. That error message seems informative, have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `base64.b64decode` in the server side.

For testing, I read the image from file, instead of using `camera.read()`.

I converted the code to Python 3 (sorry)...

- Python 3 strings ate Unicode, so I replaced `b64encode` and `b64decode` with `encodebytes` and `decodebytes`.
- I replaced `send` with `sendall` (I am not sure if it's required or not).
- I added `cv2.waitKey(1000)` after `cv2.imshow('img.jpg',image)`
- I added few modifications that I am not sure if necessary (like setting IP address to localhost).

Please keep in mind that I am still learning Python (my code might not be most elegant).

---

Client code:

```
import socket
import cv2
import threading
import time 
import base64

Soket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2344
#Buffer_Boyutu = 2360
Soket.bind(('127.0.0.1', port)) 
Soket.listen(20)
c,asa = Soket.accept()
c.sendall(b'')
camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)

def img_to_str(image):
    ret, buff = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    str_image = base64.encodebytes(buff.tobytes())
    c.sendall(str(len(str_image)).encode('utf-8'))
    str_image = base64.encodebytes(buff.tobytes())
    return str_image

#ret,image=camera.read()

# For testing, read image from file
image = cv2.imread('im.png')

str_image = img_to_str(image)

print(len(str_image))
time.sleep(0.02)
c.sendall(str_image)
time.sleep(5)
Soket.close()
```

---

Server code:

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

Soket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
port = 2344
Buffer_Size = 1024
Soket.connect(('127.0.0.1',port))

def str_to_image(str_img):
    #file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(str_img), dtype=np.uint8)
    buff = base64.decodebytes(str_img)  # Decode base64
    file_bytes = np.frombuffer(buff, np.uint8)  # Convert to numpy array
    image = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    if image is None:
        print('Invalid image')
    else:
        cv2.imshow('img.jpg',image)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)

size = ''
while size == '':

    size= Soket.recv(1024)
    if size != '':

        Buffer_Size = int(size)     

        str_img = Soket.recv(Buffer_Size)
        if len(str_img) == Buffer_Size:
            str_to_image(str_img)

Soket.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```